# What's the LINQ'ish way to do this

Tags: c#, linq

Say, I have an array of lists, and I want to get a count of all of the items in all of the lists.  How would I calculate the count with LINQ?  (just general curiosity here)

Here's the old way to do it:

```
List<item>[] Lists = // (init the array of lists)
int count = 0;
foreach(List<item> list in Lists)
  count+= list.Count;
return count;
```

How would you LINQify that? (c# syntax, please)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `Sum()` method:

```
int summedCount = Lists.Sum(l => l.Count);
```

Comment: @Travis: not at all. Var is not a requirement in any situation except in the use of anonymous types. In all other cases, it is 'true' linq to use var or a strong type as the developer pleases, there is no practical difference for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 12):

I like @jrista's answer better than this but you could do

```
int summedCount = Lists.SelectMany( x => x ).Count();
```

Just wanted to show the SelectMany usage in case you want to do other things with a collection of collections.

Comment: Nice way to describe SelectMany. +1

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to be fancy

```
 int summedCount = Lists.Aggregate(0, (acc,list) => acc + list.Count);
```

But the first answer is definitely the best.